# TCP message limit with socket

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, asyncsocket

I get a strange behaviour using an asynchronous TCP server socket.
I'm following this [Microsoft example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fx6588te)

First, I find that with the code provided in the example I can make successfully only a first TCP request (I change to code to handle my required modbus implementation) because in the example is indicated that after the server sends a response it has to close the handler:

```
Public Shared Sub sendCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    ' Retrieve the socket from the state object.
    'Dim handler As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)

    ' Complete sending the data to the remote device.
    Dim bytesSent As Integer = handler.EndSend(ar)
    'Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent)

    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
    handler.Close()
    ' Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set()
End Sub
```

But then, when I make a second request with a TCP client, an error happen (cannot access a close object or something similar). Allright, I changed the code commented the two lines:

```
'handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
'handler.Close()
```

And that everything is fine...for a "n" requests.
**I found that after 32767 message (on win7) and after 2500 (on a very old XP) the server refuse the request, and is necessary to reconnect the client.
Here the relevant part of the code:**

```
Public Shared listener = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
```

The the accept part:

```
listener.Bind(localEP)
listener.Listen(100)

While True
    ' Set the event to nonsignaled state.
    allDone.Reset()

    ' Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
    listener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf acceptCallback), listener)

    ' Wait until a connection is made and processed before continuing.
    allDone.WaitOne()
End While
```

The callback:

```
Public Shared Sub acceptCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        ' Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set()

        ' Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Dim listener As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        ' End the operation.
        handler = listener.EndAccept(ar)

        ' Create the state object for the async receive.
        Dim state As New StateObject

        While handler.Connected
            state.workSocket = handler
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf readCallback), state)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        File.AppendAllText("log.txt", ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace & vbCrLf)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Sub readCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    ' Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    ' from the asynchronous state object.
    Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
    handler = state.workSocket
    Dim rxBuf(12) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    handler = state.workSocket
    Try
        ' Read data from the client socket. 
        'If (handler.Connected = False) Then
        '    handler = listener.EndAccept(ar)
        'End If

        Dim read As Integer = handler.EndReceive(ar)

        ' Data was read from the client socket.
        If read >= 12 Then
            ReDim rxBuf(read - 1)
            For i = 0 To read - 1
                rxBuf(i) = state.buffer(i)
            Next
            'Array.Clear(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length)
            TCPRequestRespond(rxBuf, handler)
            'Else
            '    ' Not all data received. Get more.
            '    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            '                         New AsyncCallback(AddressOf readCallback), state)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim s As String = ex.StackTrace.ToString
        File.AppendAllText("log.txt", ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace & vbCrLf)
    End Try
End Sub 'readCallback
```

The:

```
 Dim read As Integer = handler.EndReceive(ar)
```

Is where I get the error if I do not comments the 2 previous indicated lines.
Then the TCPRequestRespond simply create the message and then start sending it:

```
handler.BeginSend(TxBuf, 0, txCount, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf sendCallback), handler)
```

The send callback is the first reported in this question.
Any Idea? I found it really strange that the server use a limited request response number.
I found a lot of documentation about the limit of the ephemeral port, but that's not the case (we have only one connection).

Comment: Why did you tag this question C# when all the code is in VB?

Comment: @JonSkeet : For some reason people always seem to confuse the two.

Comment: Sorry :) I forget to indicate that I tryed the M$ example with the 2 languages, because I found a different line for the ManualResetEvent in the 2 implementation. Of course the code is in VB, which is the runtime one